# Integrate JWT (JSON Web Token) service with Vapor for Sign in function

Tags: swift, authentication, jwt, vapor

I'm integrating JWT (JSON Web Token) service with Vapor for the auth process, but I'm getting a runtime error (attached below) when trying to run the Vapor project.

> Swift/ErrorType.swift:200: Fatal error: Error raised at top level:
> JWTKit error: signing algorithm error: bioConversionFailure 2022-07-03
> 13:54:31.334671+0300 Run[29671:440363] Swift/ErrorType.swift:200:
> Fatal error: Error raised at top level: JWTKit error: signing
> algorithm error: bioConversionFailure

- **Note:**
  I used the commands below, and “cd" the vapor project path for downloading the keys [Private and the Public]:
- 1️⃣ For the private key: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM -f myjwt.key`
- 2️⃣ For the public key: `openssl rsa -in myjwt.key -pubout -outform PEM -out myjwt.key pub`

***P.S.:***
I would be grateful if you could provide me a resource that I can follow for JWT with Vapor, since there's a lack of resources regarding that topic.

Comment: That error means the key isn't in the correct format. It's hard to see what's going on without any code but the Vapor docs show how to load an RSA key and what they should look like https://docs.vapor.codes/security/jwt/#rsa